# JQuery changing colour of Div

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

My Javascript/jQuery is a little rusty so this may be glaringly obvious but, I have a div and want it to change colour when clicked which I can do using

```
$(".MyClass").on("click", function()
{
    $(this).css("background", "#0077af");
});
```

I have now tried to incorporate this into a boolean if statement so that if clicked it changes colour, then if clicked again it changes back, so on and so forth, however it now does nothing.

```
<script>
boolean clicked = false;
$(".League").on("click", function()
{
  if(clicked == false)
  {
     $(this).css("background", "#0077af");
     clicked = true;
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).css("background", "#00aeff");
    clicked = false;
  }
});
</script>
```

My knowledge of Java is stronger than Javascript and knowledge of jQuery very limited so nothing too complex please :)

Comment: I'd suggest learning to use the browser's developer console (usually accessed by F12). If you'd ran the code with the console open, you would have seen that `boolean` was unrecognised.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I'm on Mac Safari but I think I know what you are referencing, I'll check that out it in future, thank you.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change your variable initialisation statement

```
boolean clicked = false;
```

to

```
var clicked = false;
```

and best to use `"backround-color"` rather than `"background"`